# Removing index.php rewrite not working

Tags: htaccess

I use the official EE rewrite rule to remove index.php. This has always worked for me just fine... until now. I am using a hosting company that I've not used before and it is acting funny.

The problem: all routes are getting passed to the main index template, as if there were no additional url segments.

Here is what I'm using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|mp3|mov|mp4|tiff|ico|tif)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Anyone seen this issue before?

Update: I am using an A Small Orange shared plan.

**The solution:**
In config.rb, I needed to change this...

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

to...

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: The `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';` works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adjusting your uri_protocol settings. When I have experienced these issues it has always been solved by specifying "PATH_INFO" or "ORIG_PATH_INFO".

Comment: Yes, that is it! I actually had to use REQUEST_URI, but that was it. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

The one I've been using has a nice little comment that might help you:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine On 
 # Removes index.php 
 RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] 
 # If 404s, "No Input File" or every URL returns the same thing 
 # make it /index.php?/$1 above (add the question mark)
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yeah, tried that... no luck. Also, my issue isn't 404s... it is all routes getting passed to the main index template. In other words the homepage is the only page that'll show.

Comment: You might want to mention the name of your hosting company ... someone else hosting there might have the immediate solution for you.

Comment: Good idea. Done.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you why, but this is what I have.  I host several sites with ASO and it has always worked for me.  It's also possible there is something in there that isn't needed. I've just hated to mess with something that has worked!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.+) $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

The one I use (which always works for me on MediaTemple DV hosting) is slightly different. Maybe it'll work for you:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^/index.php
RewriteCond $1 !.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Same issue with that one. grrr :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a `?` after `index.php`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel dumb for not realizing this before searching, but since this does in fact fix this problem for me: make sure the Apache rewrite module is actually turned on:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

(for Ubuntu)