# After removing index.php from URLs, 404s on every template except homepage

Tags: url, htaccess, 404, links, index

**UPDATE**

When first posting this, I didn't understand the problem. When I removed the index.php from the urls with a .htaccess file (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html), all the templates other than the homepage all gave 404s.

**ORIGINAL POST**

I've create a list of the channel entries, but when you click on a link it sends you to the url example.com/title-permalink= and throws up a 404.

I've tried to visit the single entry pages by manually putting in the url but it doesn't work either.

Here's the simple code on the index page.

```
<ul>
   {exp:channel:entries channel="essays"}
      <li><a href="title-permalink="site/essay"}">{title}</a></li>
   {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

And the single entry page.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="essays"}
   <h1>{title}</h1>
   {body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I haven't had this problem before. It seems like it must be really simple. What am I missing? Something in the settings?

Comment: UPDATE
Just did a fresh install and repeated the setup and everything, trying to figure out when it went wrong. It's **when I removed the index.php from the urls**. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html I tried the recommended exceptions, but with no luck. All templates were bringing up 404s except the homepage. Just as described at the bottom on the instructions. It's happened both on locally with MAMP and on Bluehost.

Comment: I found these questions that seem to fit the problem. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4954/404-error-on-all-templates-but-homepage-after-removing-index-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem: After trying to remove the index.php from the urls with a .htaccess file (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html), all the templates other than the homepage all gave 404s. I looked around, tried lots of different versions of the .htaccess code, and this one it worked. https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/871/3177

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^/index.php
RewriteCond $1 !.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It worked on both my local build with MAMP and my hosting on Bluehost, both in sub-directories.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the opening `{` on the `href`'s tag, and `{title_permalink}` has an underscore `_` not a dash.

```
<li><a href="{title_permalink="site/essay"}">{title}</a></li>
```

See [EE Docs on Permalinks](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#disable)

Comment: Thanks. Always the little things. The links now points to the right url (like http://example.com/site/essay/my-first-post) but the single entry page still doesn't come up. It gets a 404.

Comment: @Nathaniel do you have a `site.group` template folder with a `essay.html` template in it?

Comment: Yes, template group "site" and the templates "index" and "essay" within.

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file configured? What happens when you visit `/index.php/site/essay`?

Comment: I only set up the .htaccess to remove index.php from the urls. I get a 404 when I visit index.php/site/essay. Actually I get a 404 when I try and visit any template other than the home page. Maybe that's the real problem...

Answer (score 0):

On single entry pages that aren't throwing 404's EE is falling back to the template group's index.html page.

To fix:

Add this to the top of your detail page template. Adjust the segment to a number AFTER your URL Title displays:

```
{if segment_3 != ""}
  {redirect="404"}
{/if}
```

And on single entry pages you should do this to trigger 404's when EE can't find an entry so that it does not fallback to the index.html template in the template group. Adjust the segment to your URL Title segment:

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel="ch_blog"
  limit="1"
  require_entry="yes"
  url_title="{segment_2}"
  status="open"
  disable="{gv_param_disable_default}"
  dynamic="no"
}
```

Finally, add these to your .htaccess file (where /index.php/site/404 points to your 404 template):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php/site/404

<FilesMatch "(\.jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|css|js|flv)$">
  ErrorDocument 404 "File Not Found"
</FilesMatch>
```

That should do it!

Comment: Just curious - why turn dynamic off and force url_title on a single entry template?

Comment: I copied this code from a recent 2.8.1 project. For some reason "require_entry" was super finicky and wouldn't work without explicitly setting the URL title as a parameter.

Comment: It's not just the single entry pages, it's every single template other than the homepage. I went through the install, setup process again to figure this out. It's when I removed the index.php. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html With the problem better understood, I'm searching around for answers.